# Certain events, are they only associated with bounties?

Tags: diablo-iii

There are a few events and things within Westmarch Commons that I have been trying to get for the last several days. I have seen some stuff online about them also being associated with bounties.

The three I am trying to get, are as follows:

- The Angered Dead
- Tolifer's Last Stand
- A Shameful Death

Are these events only accessible via a bounty, or can they also be found during your first playthrough, and first time in Westmarch Commons? I play in Hardcore mode, on normal.